# How to iterate an array of HTML <div> elements and style another element differently for each index number?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

I would like the `content` value of a `div`'s pseudo-element `::after` to change following the index number of 6 child `div` elements, on hover over each of these 6 divs.

I am stuck at creating a first array of the 6 divs and another array containing the 6 infos to display with the same corresponding index number.

Array #1 would be [.hov-sq:nth-child(1), .hov-sq:..] and array #2 would be the content for the 'data-content' attribute to change at each hover ['digital nomad','digital developer','superman','etc...]

So far I managed to change the pseudo-element content using this jQuery code and CSS code.

```js
$('.hov-sq').hover(function() {
  $('.c-1').attr('data-content', 'frontend developer');
});
```

```css
.landing-hov-s {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.hov-sq {
  width: 33.3333333vw;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.c-1::after {
  /* other styling not relevant to issue */
  content: attr(data-content) '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-hov-s">
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
</div>
<div class="c-1">
  <h1>Laurent<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrette</h1>
</div>
```

The page is live here for a proper display: http://vmax.laurentchevrette.digital/

Comment: Could you give a clearer description of what you're trying to do. Your snippet seems to work as you suggest, you just need to ad more content to it

Comment: Hi thanks I really tried to make it clear but I'll update it with a little more info, didn'T want to make it too long either. Thanks!

Comment: basically I want the content of the ::after of .c-1 to change whenever the mouse of the user hovers over the 6 divs on the landing page in order to swap the 6 differnt info texts about me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to determine the index of which element within the collection is being hovered

```js
const content = ['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4','Item 5','Item 6'];

const $sq = $('.hov-sq').hover(function() {
  const idx = $sq.index(this);
  $('.c-1').attr('data-content', content[idx]);
}, function(){
   // remove when mouse leaves if wanted 
   $('.c-1').attr('data-content','')
});
```

```css
.landing-hov-s {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.hov-sq {
  width: 33.3333333vw;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.c-1::after {
  /* other styling not relevant to issue */
  content: attr(data-content) '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-hov-s">
  <div class="hov-sq">One</div>
  <div class="hov-sq">Two</div>
  <div class="hov-sq">Three</div>
  <div class="hov-sq">Four</div>
  <div class="hov-sq">Five</div>
  <div class="hov-sq">Six</div>
</div>
<div class="c-1">
  <h1>Laurent<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrette</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been stuck on that for a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery's index method

If you are using jQuery, [you have access to the `index()` method](https://api.jquery.com/index/#:%7E:text=index()%20is%20called%20on,is%20passed%20as%20an%20argument%2C%20.).

Also I've added the function that will run once mouse is `out` of the hovered div.

That said, be wary that you cannot select pseudoelements y Javascript, so you should use attribute selectors in CSS as shown belown to style them.

```js
$('.hov-sq').hover(function() {
  $('.c-1')
    .attr('data-content', 'frontend developer')
    .attr('data-index', $(this).index());
  console.log($(this).index())
}, function() {
  $('.c-1')
    .attr('data-content', '')
    .attr('data-index', '');
});
```

```css
.landing-hov-s {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.hov-sq {
  width: 33.3333333vw;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.c-1::after {
  /* other styling not relevant to issue */
  content: attr(data-content) '';
}

.c-1[data-index="0"]::after {
  /* Style for index 0 */
}


/* Rest of the styles */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-hov-s">
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
  <div class="hov-sq"></div>
</div>

<div class="c-1">
  <h1>Laurent<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Chevrette</h1>
</div>
```